# how to extract some text after a specific word in Excel

Tags: excel

how can I extract some text after a specific word in Excel

"**1 GB RAM** 2 MP Front Camera 12.7 cm (5) IPS Display 2000 mAh Battery Android 4.2 Jellybean Expandable Up To 32 GB 1.5 GHz 12 MP Rear Camera with Flash 4 GB Internal Memory"

"10.16 cm (4) WVGA IPS Display 1.3GHz Quad Core Processor **2 GB RAM** and 8 GB ROM 5 MP Rear and VGA Front Dual Sim (3G+2G) GSM OS Version : Android Kitkat v4.4 FM Radio : YES Wi-Fi : YES Battery 1500 mAH 1 Year Brand Warranty"

In above two cell I want to extract

1 GB RAM from first cell
2 GB RAM from second cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, if "# GB RAM" is consistent for all data.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("GB RAM",A1)-2,8)
```

Comment: Yes it is working but the correct formula is =MID(A1,FIND("GB RAM",A1)-2,8)

Comment: yeah, most laptop uses , instead of ;. Just happen that mine accepts ;.

Comment: Just watch out for double-digit RAM values. With the formula given, you will get 2 GB RAM instead of 32 GB RAM and 6 GB RAM instead of 16 GB RAM. You may be better off with =TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("GB RAM",A1)-3,9), but you would need to add a leading space to all the cells so that you don't run into errors with strings that start with "# GB". Of course this still won't work for 3-digit values for the number of GB.

Comment: it is working even for 3 digit for example  32 GB RAM use  =MID(A1,FIND("GB RAM",A1)-3,9) and for 128 GB RAM use  =MID(A1,FIND("GB RAM",A1)-4,10)